# PJSIP: Why am I able to make calls but logged as unavailable in the Asterisk 16 console?

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

So i can make calls but i'am offline in the console. I don't get notice in the console when I register Why that ? thanks.

## PJSIP.conf

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0

[7000]
type=endpoint
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=g729
transport=transport-udp
auth=7000
aors=7000

[7000]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=7000
username=7000

[7000]
type=aor
qualify_timeout=4.0
qualify_frequency=50
max_contacts=1
```

## Cmd: pjsip show endpoints

```
 Endpoint:  7000                                                 Unavailable   0 of inf
     InAuth:  7000/7000
        Aor:  7000                                               1
  Transport:  transport-udp             udp      0      0  0.0.0.0:5060
```

## Cmd: pjsip show endpoint 7000

```
Endpoint:  7000                                                 Unavailable   0 of inf
     InAuth:  7000/7000
        Aor:  7000                                               1
  Transport:  transport-udp             udp      0      0  0.0.0.0:5060
```

Comment: Try setting `qualify=yes` in sip.conf file then reload and see on asterisk cmd

Comment: @Riad I'im using pjsip. I just tried wiyh pjsip i get  pjsip show endpoint 7000
Unable to find object 7000

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `allow_subscribe=yes` ;)

```
Endpoint:  7000                                                 In use        1 of inf
     InAuth:  7000/7000
        Aor:  7000                                               1
      Contact:  7000/sip:7000@127.0.0.1:62210;ob           a891149c2b Avail         1.464
  Transport:  transport-udp             udp      0      0  0.0.0.0:5060
    Channel: PJSIP/7000-00000001/Playback                        Up            00:00:03
        Exten: 999                       CLCID: "" <>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do outbound call by using sip response "Authentification required" and authentification after that.

For incoming call need "registration", when your device use it asterisk will record ip/port pair for use for incoming calls. That pair can be any if your device have no public ip(NAT).